# How do I find out why my template gives me an error

Tags: c#, wix, visual-studio-templates

We have an old template builded with the nuget package ligershark/template-builder.

Now I am updating this template with a wix project. When doing that I get the following error message:
"The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct."

I understand that I must have been linking something wrong, but I have searched for ages now and find nothing wrong. I have also tried to run it through visual studio but I only get the same error message with no stack trace or anything.

Is here anyone here that have investigated a similar issue? How did you approach this error? Is it possible to find logs somewhere?

Comment: My issue is solved and the reason was that I have an incompatible version of wix (3.11 that only works for vs 2017 on my machine and the template is on vs 2015). However I leave the thread open since the actual error looking could still be interesting to see if someone have any suggestions.